# How to make group mandatory if other group is found more than once

Tags: c++, regex, boost, match, boost-regex

Here is my regex so far :

```
^((([a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]+)[ ])+((\bPHONE_NUMBER\b)|(\b(IP|EMAIL)_ADDRESS\b))[ ]*[;]*[ ]*)+$
```

I would like to make at least one `;` mandatory if I found another `(([a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]+)[ ])+((\bPHONE_NUMBER\b)|(\b(IP|EMAIL)_ADDRESS\b))` after the first one.

`/tests/phone PHONE_NUMBER ; /tests/IP IP_ADDRESS` should match.

`/tests/phone PHONE_NUMBER /tests/IP IP_ADDRESS` should not match.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can do that. Use **Recursive Regex** for that.

```
^(((\s*(([\w_\/-]+)\s)((\bPHONE_NUMBER\b)|(\b(IP|EMAIL)_ADDRESS\b))\s*))(;|$)(?1)*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/dE2nK2/3

### Explanation

1. `(?1)` is a recursive regex to repeat the regex pattern of group 1. If you want to do recursive regex for the whole string, use `(?R)`, but you won't be able to use beginning anchor `^`.
2. `(;|$)` the matched regex should be ended with either `;` or the end of the string `$`.
3. Use `\s` for whitespace instead of `[ ]`.
4. `;*` and `[;]*` is same.

You can learn more about the recursive regex here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating is ugly in general, but in cases like this the most efficient way is repeating the pattern:

```
FOO(;FOO)+
```

(Replace `FOO` with your `(([a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]+)[ ])+((\bPHONE_NUMBER\b)|(\b(IP|EMAIL)_ADDRESS\b))` + some whitespaces if needed)